# Interpreting Accept Headers as intended in IE and Webkit

Tags: internet-explorer, rest, http-headers

I developed a web app that responds with data in the format as specified by the client in the [HTTP Accept Headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1). Everything worked fine while using Firefox, but when I wanted to check my CSS / HTML on Chrome and IE, both of them wanted to download the index page, as if it's an unknown content type.

After some research I found [this article](http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/page/browser-rest-http-accept-headers), which states that IE sends out a lot of crud in it's HTTP Accept headers, amongst others a list of `image/*` content types right at the start.

This caused my web app to try to send the index page as an `image/jpeg`.

**So how do I know when to ignore and when to use the Accept Headers?**

Comment: What content-type does your application choose if you try to access the page with IE? Even if IEs Accept header may be broken, it should still match "text/html".

Comment: It matches against image/jpeg, as the app can serve images as well. It's in the question :P

Comment: OK, I assumed that the index page would only exist as HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is likely to apply your own server-side weight if there are types with the same weight in the accept header. Thus if you have text/html and image/* both with the same q-value (or none) you could give text/html preference by default.

Comment: I wanted to implement this now, and realised (again) that the problem is that IE doesn't send text/html as a MIME type, just a lot of cruft and */*. So even if I weigh text/html more than image/*, it will still pick image/*, as there is not text/html.

Comment: What exactly does your IE send?

Comment: Check this link. I also mention it in the question:
http://www.gethifi.com/blog/browser-rest-http-accept-headers

Answer (score 0):

I would simply keep a blacklist of programs that send obviously broken Accept headers, like IE and Safari (according to the article). If the User-Agent header matches the blacklist, ignore the Accept header, otherwise don't.

The problem with IEs Accept header is not that it puts `image/*` at the start, but that it doesn't indicate that it prefers HTML or XHTML over images (via the `q` parameter). AFAIK, the order of the elements in the Accept header is not significant.

Comment: Whitelist: Yea, true, the only problem is that User-Agent headers are sometimes untrustworthy, so I try to stay away from them.

Order of elements: The parser I use assumes that if no preference is given, the first takes precedence.